# How to show tooltip when mouse pointer moves on an item drawn in QAbstractItemView subclass?

Tags: c++, qt, charts

I've implemented `QAbstractItemView` to show a tabular model (having two columns, one for x axis another for corresponding y axis) in [line chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aScientificGraphSpeedVsTime.svg) style. To do that I reimplemented `QAbstractItemView::paintEvent()`. The chart is now shown and each data is drawn by a little circle. When mouse pointer hovers over the circles (representing (x, y) on the chart for some data) I want to show tooltip that will display original data in (x, y) format. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already done it, you should redefine the `QAbstractItemView::indexAt` function, which returns the `QModelIndex` at a given position in the view.

And in your model, you should set the tooltip text for your indexes as the role `Qt::ToolTipRole` or make your custom model `QAbstractItemModel::data()` function returns that text dynamically when asked for that role.

Comment: i found it very hard to do. so i'm moving over scene-view technique to draw the chart.